# java.lang.NullPointerException by Geocoder with GeoTools and Shapefiles

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, reverse-geocoding, geotools

I am new to java and try to use a Reverse Geocode Script from Geotools. But I always get a java.lang.NullPointerException. Can someone help me?

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
> org.locationtech.jts.geom.Envelope.intersects(Envelope.java:528)  at
> org.locationtech.jts.index.strtree.STRtree$3.intersects(STRtree.java:108)
> at
> org.locationtech.jts.index.strtree.AbstractSTRtree.query(AbstractSTRtree.java:256)
> at org.locationtech.jts.index.strtree.STRtree.query(STRtree.java:205)
> at
> org.geotools.data.collection.SpatialIndexFeatureCollection.subCollection(SpatialIndexFeatureCollection.java:152)
> at com.company.SimpleGeoCoder.lookup(SimpleGeoCoder.java:53)    at
> com.company.Main.main(Main.java:60)

```
public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();
            SimpleGeoCoder geocoder = new SimpleGeoCoder();
            Point london = gf.createPoint(new Coordinate(0.0, 51.0));
            SimpleFeatureCollection features = geocoder.lookup(london);
            SimpleFeatureIterator itr = features.features();
            try {
                while (itr.hasNext()) {
                    SimpleFeature f = itr.next();
                    System.out.println(f.getAttribute("NAME"));
                }
            } finally {
                itr.close();
            }
                            }
                }



    public class SimpleGeoCoder {
    
            SpatialIndexFeatureCollection countries;
            final static FilterFactory2 ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2();
            final static public String countryFile = "countries.shp";
    
            public SimpleGeoCoder() throws IOException {
                URL countryURL = URLs.fileToUrl(new File(this.countryFile));
                HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("url", countryURL);
                DataStore ds = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);
                if (ds == null) {
                    throw new IOException("couldn't open " + params.get("url"));
                }
                Name name = ds.getNames().get(0);
               this.countries = new SpatialIndexFeatureCollection(ds.getFeatureSource(name).getFeatures());
            }
    
            public SimpleFeatureCollection lookup(Point p) {
                    Filter f = ff.contains(ff.property("the_geom"), ff.literal(p));
              return this.countries.subCollection(f);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I've just tried your code and it works for me when I use the Natural Earth 10M country outlines (when i changed NAME to name) - where did you get your countries file from? what does it contain?

Comment: That's interesting.
Iam using the 10m_admin_0_countries.shp from http://naturalearthdata.com/. Coulde it be related to the Java version or the Geotool Version?

Comment: difficult to say when you didn't specify either in your question :-)

Comment: Of course xD. Iam using the IntelliJ IDEA, java version 13.0.1, Geotools Version 24 Snapshot. I've tried to test with  System.out.println(); to check for missing content but it seems values are always transferred up to the last line code (return this.countries.subCollection(f);).

Comment: GeoTools doesn't support Java versions other than 8 & 11.

Comment: Okay I changed the Java version to 11 and still have the same Problem. I can't find the problem. Is there another way to RefersGeocode with Geotools?

Comment: Try removing the spatialIndex wrapper - but as I said it works for me as is with Java8

Comment: and with java 11

Comment: I couldn't make it work. Could it be the imports? I can't imagine any other difference between your design and mine.

Comment: What exactly did you change ?

Comment: See the full working example at https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2000261

Comment: thanks for that. But now I'm getting null value for the result. Is there a further step or am I doing something wrong ? Returns: 11.0.5+10-b520.30
the_geom
null

Comment: may be you need to switch the axis order of your test point?

Comment: true that was the case. Now there is no more zero value but also no name returned.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you used the example from this gist (https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/15776) and yon need to update some imports to make it work

Replace

```java
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;
```

with

```java
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point;
```

It was so simple, but it took me 3 hours to find out how to fix it.